# How to use mixins to share attributes with pony orm

Tags: python, inheritance, mixins, ponyorm

Is there any way to share the attribute definition for entities in pony.orm?
I have a couple of classes that are not related to each other but I want them to have the same attributes. Currently I copy paste them from class to class but once I change the wording or add/remove an attribute this is lots of manual work.

Is there any way to transform this

```py
class ClassA(db.Entity):
    primary: str = orm.PrimaryKey(str)

    classa_key1: str = orm.Required(str)
    classa_key2: str = orm.Required(str)
    classa_key3: str = orm.Required(str)
    ...

    some_key1: str = orm.Required(str)
    some_key2: str = orm.Required(str)
    ...

class ClassB(db.Entity):
    primary: str = orm.PrimaryKey(str)

    classb_key1: str = orm.Required(str)
    classb_key2: str = orm.Required(str)
    classb_key3: str = orm.Required(str)
    ...

    some_key1: str = orm.Required(str)
    some_key2: str = orm.Required(str)
    ...
```

into something like this?

```py
class SomeKeyMixin:
    some_key1: str = orm.Required(str)
    some_key2: str = orm.Required(str)
    ...


class ClassA(db.Entity, SomeKeyMixin):
    primary: str = orm.PrimaryKey(str)

    classa_key1: str = orm.Required(str)
    classa_key2: str = orm.Required(str)
    classa_key3: str = orm.Required(str)
    ...


class ClassB(db.Entity, SomeKeyMixin):
    primary: str = orm.PrimaryKey(str)

    classb_key1: str = orm.Required(str)
    classb_key2: str = orm.Required(str)
    classb_key3: str = orm.Required(str)
    ...
```

Normal inheritance doesn't work because this will put all classes into the same table and this is not desired.

Comment: I can't comment specifically for pony.orm, but this is indeed how Mixins generally work. It is a separate Class that has some kind of base configuration and you include it as an argument of a class you want to inherit from it. Have you tried this implementation? Does it give any errors?

Comment: The code works without errors, but pony doesn't include the fields when accessing and creating the db. But obviously I want the db mapping

Comment: have you looked into metaclasses? I think it's the only way to get additional fields into class' `__dict__`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems to be impossible to achieve what you want using Pony. That's what they say in the documentation. They offer only one way to implement inheritance and it's putting everything in one table.

https://docs.ponyorm.org/entities.html#representing-inheritance-in-the-database

Comment: If I underestand right, mixins in pony  works, but all classes is in one table. Problem isn't in functionality problem is "only" in database mapping.